# SPSS Syntax Font

Tags: syntax, fonts, spss

I prefer the font of my syntax being unicode (like courier new). However whenever I open a Syntax file, only the commands are displayed in the selected font, but not the comments . Only when I close the syntax and then open it again, everything is displayed in the selected font. Is there a setting that I may have overlooked that causes the font to remain as selected? It's quite tedious to open the syntax twice each time.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in version 25. Since I upgraded my installation last week I have the same problem. Here is another post about this issue, unfortunatly without any solution: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/411965/spss-25-syntax-editor-font-type.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest version of SPSS (v26, fix pack 1).